# Solving topological errors like invalid geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, topology, invalid-data

I use QGIS, version 2.18.9. 
I´ve several polygon-shapes with topological errors. Before I tried to apply the "intersection"-tool and got the message: Input layer A contains invalid geometries (feature 77). Unable to complete intersection algorithm.
Firstly, I used the "check-validity"-tool, which detected some line-intersection and double nodes.

Then, I tried the "topology checker" with "must not have invalid geometries".

I´ve had the impression, that all errors where found then. So I applied the LWGEOM algorithms "Make valid" but got a error another messages ([error 87] falscher Parameter see log for more details).

I´m an absolute QGIS-beginner. So, I have not a single idea how to solve this problem. It has to be a simple automatically way, ´cause I´ve a big dataset here.

Answer (score 10):

The most successful way I've ever had of correcting topological errors in QGIS is actually to use GRASS.  You can either:

1. run v.clean from the processing toolbox (manual here https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/v.clean.html);
2. use the 'Repair Geometry' plugin (which is an automation of the v.clean tool); or if all else fails
3. import the dataset into GRASS proper and then export it out again as whatever format you want

I've never had number 3 fail for me and there is a good walkthrough of how to do it here: https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/bad-bad-polygon-fixing-invalid-geometries-with-quantum-gis/

Comment: Thank you Ed. Yesterday I tried the intersection tool with an older version (2.18.0) an got at least with two layers no other problems. Maybe it is the version which causes the problems. But nevertheless I had the same problems with another layer. I guess, I´ll try your suggestions. V. clean I already applied but didn´t understand...

Comment: V.clean is a bit daunting as it gives you so many options to try. I'd recommend the Repair Geometry plugin to streamline it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

[LWGEOM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/processinglwgeomprovider/) is good option to fix geometry, works for my problems (like "invalid geometry") well.
@Sophie B., your [error 87] might be solved by correct path definition to LWGEOM binaries. You need to locate it and set it in *Processing > Options >> Providers >> LWGEOM algorithms*, see screenshot below (QGIS v2.18.15).

[image: Processing > Options >> Providers >> LWGEOM algorithms]

Then you can validate the results with *Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Validity*, or by [Topology Checker](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) plugin.

Comment: Careful just for this, seen on the git : "Plugin DOESN'T work with postgis 2.0.* installations"

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Geometry Checker plugin. This tool let you also to check geometry validity, properties, condition and of course topology. If you have a big dataset and return hundreds of errors. Try to fix it several times. Check out [this post](http://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html) which describe how to clean topological error with Geometry checker and also v.clean tool. The result from using each tool is also compared. So you can get a better understanding in using the tools