# Combining two areas on a shapefile (two polygons) into one

Tags: qgis, polygon, combine

I am trying to combine two polygons or areas on a map into one.   I have added a field called region to try and dissolve the borders by region.  This did not work.  I am now trying to combine them using merge selected features in QGIS but I get the error:

[image]

Comment: Does your geometry have any errors? Try using `'Check Validity...'` Can you describe additionally what happen when your proceed with `'Dissolve'`?

Comment: Try using the tool `Vector > Geometry tools > Multiparts to singleparts`, before `dissolve` tool

Comment: @Taras I ran the validity checker:    
Execution completed in 0.27 seconds
Results:
{'ERROR_COUNT': 56,
'ERROR_OUTPUT': 'Error_output_3c98c864_43d7_49ac_a0c8_fa6553e691e1',
'INVALID_COUNT': 56,
'INVALID_OUTPUT': 'Invalid_output_6cacb41f_91e3_4700_ac9c_d0b0b31a9873',
'VALID_COUNT': 0,
'VALID_OUTPUT': 'Valid_output_1b1301c1_b199_4a9a_86ed_f6f08a02ef13'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Check validity' finished

Comment: @Pjhooker I ran the desolve but it gives a layer called dissolved that has nothing in it

Comment: @taras I get this error when trying to dissolve by region:    
Feature (3) has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the "Ignore invalid input features" option.
Execution failed after 0.08 seconds

Comment: Seems like to have to clean your geometry firstly.

Comment: @Taras thanks... I am new at learning QGIS.  How do I clean the geometry?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can start with searching on the Internet: *"qgis fix topology errors"*. Check these threads: [Solving topological errors like invalid geometries in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250438/solving-topological-errors-like-invalid-geometries-in-qgis) and [Geodose | How to Clean Topology Error in QGIS](https://www.geodose.com/2017/10/how-to-clean-topology-error-in-qgis.html).