# Can select polygon in attribute table but not in map canvas

Tags: qgis-3

I'm working with a shapefile where polygons are digitized with topology errors, they are overlapping slightly. I can select one polygon in the attribute table but not in the map canvas. Also, for this polygon I found out that it's self-overlapping.

Which steps can solve this problem?

Comment: What if you try `Settings > Options > Canvas & Legend` and changing *'Selection color'* into something with `0%` Opacity. Can it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Topology can be cleaned manually which is time consuming. Install the `Geometry Checker` plugin. Then via the menu: `Vector >Geometry Tools >Check Geometries` Select your layer and check the boxes `No silver polygons` under Geometry conditions and `Check for overlaps` and `Check for gaps` under Topology checks. Select how you want to fix the errors and click 'fix'.

Alternatively, you can use GRASS GIS `v.clean` if you have QGIS with GRASS GIS modules. Although I find that to be less intuitive.

This post also has good answers: [Solving topological errors like invalid geometries in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250438/solving-topological-errors-like-invalid-geometries-in-qgis)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed most of the time geometry errors make the features graphically unselectable.
You can edit the layer and resolve the errors by manually removing self-intersection or duplicate vertices.
Also, you can try some algorithms in the processing menu that may help but are not perfect :

- repair geometry ;
- delete duplicate vertices

At last, few tools may help you to check all geometries and identify errors like algorithm `check validity`(a name approaching) in vector `menu` or `processing` again.